# how to achieve higher perfomance with maximum jquery ajax http request

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jakarta-ee

I have mimumum 5 to 6 jquery ajax call on single event. I found my site is working slow.

I think this is the reason is for taking long time to load page because page is loading all http requests.

I have put async: true and noCache:true in each ajax call.

can i have solution to resolve this ?

```
function loadData(){    

 jQuery.ajax({
    async: true,
    type: 'POST',
    url: urlPath,
    noCache:true,
    data:{
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        jQuery("#idDivResult").html(data); // result.jsp include here
        },
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {

    }
});

loadFooter();
loadCriteria();
loadNavigation();
}

loadFooter(){
     jQuery.ajax({
     .....
     success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        jQuery("#idDivFooter").html(data); // footer.jsp include here

     }
     ....
}

loadCriteria(){
     jQuery.ajax({
     .....
     success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        jQuery("#idDivCriteria").html(data); // criteria.jsp include here

     }
     ....
}

loadNavigation(){
     jQuery.ajax({
     .....
     success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        jQuery("#idDivNavigation").html(data); // navigation.jsp include here
     }
     ....
}
```

Comment: You should reduce the number of AJAX requests. Why do you need to send so many? You could also use websockets.

Comment: i have 5-6 div placed on different location on my web page and these divs will be changed as per criteria so.. for each request i got response text which i will set as innerHTML to related div.

Comment: Why can't you combine these requests into one?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: can you give me an example for combine all requests in to one ?

Comment: That depends entirely on what your application looks like. Can you post your JS code?